# Uso dell'articolo determinativo come articolo generico

Tags: word-usage, grammar, articles

> Stamattina facevo un giro nel centro della città e ho visto un negozio dove si vendevano **mele**. Sono entrato nel negozio e ho comprato **mele** (**delle mele**). Mamma mia... come amo **le mele**. Dopo, a distanza di 100 metri ho visto un fioraio che vendeva **fiori**...
>   Mi sono avvicinato al fiorario e ho chiesto quanto costavano i fiori. Ho comprato **fiori** (**dei fiori**). Devo dire che amo **i fiori**...

Nel paragrafo precedente ho scritto un testo in cui si parla di "mele" (e anche di "fiori") in generale, non di "mele specifiche". In alcune frasi si usa l'articolo determinativo, ma non in tutte: "ho visto un negozio dove si vendevano **mele**". Però... se scrivo "si vendevano **le mele**", anche così vuol dire "mele in generale", non "queste mele"?

Faccio un altro esempio:

> Entro in un negozio e chiedo: avete **candele**?

Si può anche chiedere "avete le candele?" per esprimere "candele in generale", non "candele specifiche"?

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Comment: Perché un downvote senza spiegazione? Penso che non dobbiamo trattare così i nuovi arrivati!

Comment: Non sono stato io a downvotare, ma: Il primo paragrafo sembra inutile. Il secondo contiene una domanda che è difficile da capire, anche a causa di problemi grammaticali -- secondo me sarebbe utile se l'OP provasse a riscriverla in inglese. Il terzo e quarto paragrafo contengono una domanda diversa che andrebbe chiesta separatamente. Questo lo dico per spingere l'OP a rendere più chiara la domanda, non per scoraggiarlo. Benvenuto su Italian.stackexchange!

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Nel primo paragrafo l'OP fa un esempio nel quale si parla di "mele" (e anche di "fiori") in generale, non di "mele specifiche". Nel secondo paragrafo chiede se si può esprimere la stessa idea ("mele qualsiasi", non "mele specifiche") usando l'articolo determinativo.  Nel terzo paragrafo l'OP fa un esempio nel quale si parla di "candele qualsiasi", non di "candele specifiche". Nel quarto chiede se si può esprimere la stessa idea usando l'articolo determinativo. Perlomeno è così come io capisco la domanda.

Comment: Grazie Charo. Se lei ha capito, vuol dire che mi sono spiegato. Grazie. Quasi quasi volevo abbandonare il sito. Buona giornata!

Comment: Grazie mille degli edit, ora è molto meglio.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Secondo me, è una domanda interessante. Se diciamo "un negozio dove si vende **la** frutta", si può anche dire "un negozio dove si vendono **le** mele?" (riferendosi a "frutta qualsiasi" e a "mele qualsiasi").

Comment: @Charo Sì, sono d'accordo, è una domanda interessante; non ho mai detto che non lo fosse. Ti posso dire che "avete le candele" suona leggermente insolito ma non sbagliato al mio orecchio, e che l'articolo determinativo è più comune con il singolare ("avete il nuovo iPhone?"), ma non posto una risposta perché non sono familiare con le regole grammaticali coinvolte --- è una di quelle cose su cui i madrelingua vanno a orecchio ma in fondo non conoscono bene le regole, a meno che non siano insegnanti di italiano. :)

Comment: Solitamente qui [ci diamo del tu](http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9/ci-diamo-del-tu). Cerco di aiutarti a scrivere la tua domanda in modo che si possa capire meglio. Se trovi qualcosa che non corrisponda a quello che tu intendevi, dillo per favore.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Siamo d'accordo sul fatto che spesso si usa l'articolo determinatico anche quando non “determina” qualcosa di specifico, ma “il nuovo iPhone” è invece proprio un caso da manuale di articolo determinativo (“il telefonino X” rispetto a “un telefonino”).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Penso che un esempio più adatto sia: "avete il pane?"

Comment: Se ne parla qui, http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/articolo-determinativo-e-partitivo.570349/, ma non sono sicura che quello detto corretto/completo.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Dopo aver letto [questo](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/articolo-determinativo-e-partitivo.570349/), adesso ho il dubbio se "avete il pane?" sia un esempio di uso dell'articolo determinativo per riferirsi a "qualsiasi pane" o invece si riferisca a "un pane conosciuto da entrambi gli interlocutori".

Comment: Vi saluto!
Mi correggete, per favore, se il mio ragionamento e' corretto. Se scivo, per esempio",AMO I FIORI"(vuol dire amo i fiori come il classe e dunque e' generico,Non indico QUESTI FIORI OPPURE DELLE FIORI-QUALCHE FIORI). 
"VENDETE I FIORI?"(vuol dire i fiori come il classe e dunque e' generico,Non indico QUESTI FIORI OPPURE DELLE FIORI-QUALCHE FIORI). "VENDETE FIORI?" oppure "VENDETE DEI FIORI?"(vuol dire non come il classe,ma qualche fiori della classe dei fiori).

Comment: "Mi ricordo quei mesi da un mio amico, giù Calabria.. Le cicale di giorno e i grilli di sera facevano le serenate più piacevoli, mentre le lucciole mandavano fra il grano piccoli segnali d'amore alle stelle. Dolci ricordi indimenticabili." LE CICALE, I GRILLI,LE LUCCIOLE vuol dire come il classe, non questi o quelli oppure qulache.Se qualche sarebbe DELLE CICALE, DEI GRILLI, DELLE LUCCIOLE.

Answer (score 1):

Sia con l'articolo che senza, la frase dà l'impressione di esprimere un senso di oggetto generale. Però la prima frase, ovvero "avete candele?" esprime un senso maggiore di generalità. Giusto per essere ancora più preciso, "avete le candele?" potrebbe essere benissimo preso come richiesta di candele in generale ma dà la sensazione di una certa specificità.
Mi spiego meglio, io userei "avete le candele?" se, per esempio, avessi già parlato precedentemente col negoziante del fatto che avrei comprato delle candele.
In quel caso "avete le candele?" può essere interpretato come "avete le candele di cui abbiamo parlato?".
Spero di essere stato utile :)

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Comment: Grazie DaG!!!! A me interessa quando si usano gli articoli determinativi per esprimere cose generiche, non questo oppure quello. Non quelle di che sono in conoscenza due interlocutori.

Comment: l’articolo determinativo può essere utilizzato per indicare qualcosa inteso come rappresentante di una classe...il mio esempio :icale di giorno e i grilli di sera facevano le serenate più piacevoli, mentre le lucciole mandavano fra il grano piccoli segnali d'amore alle stelle. Dolci ricordi indimenticabili." LE CICALE, I GRILLI,LE LUCCIOLE vuol dire come il classe, non questi o quelli oppure qulache.Se qualche sarebbe DELLE CICALE, DEI GRILLI, DELLE LUCCIOLE. –Qua le cicale, I grilli sono Un esempio di questa regular? Non ho specificato ne  cicale ne grilli..

Comment: “Un uomo uscì di corsa dal locale.Il locale qua esprime il modo generico???

Comment: @GhiaGvinjilia no, affatto! "dal locale" lascia intendere un locale di cui si è già parlato. O per lo meno se è la prima volta che il libro parla del locale, dovrebbe esserci una specificazione del locale stesso in seguito.
Per parlare di un locale generico di solito si usa, come ho appena fatto io, "un locale"

Comment: @G.Recchia. Grazie per la risposta. Ma se dico " dai, andiamo al ristorante per cenare"? Non specifico, intendo il ristorante, non la casa per cenare.

Comment: @GhiaGvinjilia Penso che quello sia più che altro un modo di dire o una frase fatta perché, come hai detto tu, in quel caso non si specifica il ristorante in cui si sta per andare. Però considera che dicendo "dai, andiamo ad un ristorante per cenare?" la frase avrebbe comunque senso e significherebbe la stessa cosa quindi sta a te.

Comment: @G.Recchia. Mentre stavo  parlando al telefono, ho sentito UN(IL) suono di grilli(dei grilli). Come sarebbe corretta?

Comment: W@G.Recchia Ricordo quei mesi da un mio amico, giù in Calabria.. Cicale(le cicale)  di giorno e grilli(I grilli) di sera facevano le serenate più piacevoli, mentre lucciole(le lucciole) mandavano fra il grano piccoli segnali d'amore alle stelle. Dolci ricordi indimenticabili." LE CICALE, I GRILLI,LE LUCCIOLE vuol dire come il classe, non questi o quelli oppure qualche.Se qualche sarebbe DELLE CICALE, DEI GRILLI, DELLE LUCCIOLE.Anche qua non specifico, ma perchè è corretto con articolo, se non specifico???

Comment: @GhiaGvinjilia in questo caso hanno senso entrambe le soluzioni (le cicale o delle cicale ecc...). Probabilmente io userei l'articolo perché suona leggermente meglio, ma è una finezza. Ripeto, puoi usarli entrambi. Onestamente non so dirti il perché però dicendo "le cicale" tu stai proprio specificando che stai parlando di cicale e NON di altri insetti quindi penso sia per questo che sia consentito utilizzare l'articolo determinativo

Comment: @G. Recchia Grazie.

Comment: Mentre stavo camminando sul binario, ho visto passare TRENI(DEI TRENI OPPURE I TRENI??

Comment: Un raggrupamento di polizia apri’ il fuoco per disperdere i dimostranti.(i dimostranti=generico)

Comment: @GhiaGvinjilia nel primo caso io direi "dei treni", mi sembra più generico e più appropriato. Per quanto riguarda il secondo, "i dimostranti" non mi sembra affatto generico. Mi sembra che si stia parlando di cose di cui già si conosce l'esistenza o comunque si è già parlato. Se volessi essere generico, direi anche in questo caso "dei dimostranti" :)

Comment: Grazie G. Recchia..

Comment: Mi togli un dubbio? La nozione il modo generico e "in generale" sempre è lo stesso? Come capisco:Amo i fiori(qua fiori è generico, tutti I fiori). Vendete fiori(qua fiori non sono generici, ma si usa in generale, non tutti I fiori, ma qualsiasi fiori, però che fa parte del classe dei fiori.

Comment: Non credo di aver ben capito cosa mi stai chiedendo. In ogni caso sono entrambi generici in questo caso, e non credo che ci sia una regola per poter omettere o no l'articolo. E' semplicemente una questione di come suona nel linguaggio comune. Sia "amo i fiori" che "vende fiori" indicano lo stesso grado di generalità ma non credo che ci sia una regola. Posso dirti che di solito nelle domande suona bene omettere l'articolo :)

Comment: Grazie G. Recchia

Answer (score 0):

Non sono un insegnante di Italiano ma da madrelingua provo a darti qualche suggerimento rispetto all'italiano parlato.
Analizziamo il tuo testo frase per frase:

> Stamattina facevo un giro nel centro della città e ho visto un negozio dove si vendevano mele.
>   Dopo, a distanza di 100 metri ho visto un fioraio che vendeva fiori...

ok, corrette entrambe

> Stamattina facevo un giro nel centro della città e ho visto un negozio dove si vendevano le mele. 
>   Dopo, a distanza di 100 metri ho visto un fioraio che vendeva i fiori...

ok, corrette entrambe sia in senso specifico che generico

> Stamattina facevo un giro nel centro della città e ho visto un negozio dove si vendevano delle mele.
>   Dopo, a distanza di 100 metri ho visto un fioraio che vendeva dei fiori...

ok, la più corretta per esprimere l'indeterminazione degli oggetti

> Sono entrato nel negozio e ho comprato mele.
>   Ho comprato fiori.

ok, ma suona veramente male. Da Italiano non lo direi mai....ma dipende dalla provenienza

> Sono entrato nel negozio e ho comprato le mele.
>   Ho comprato i fiori

ok. Da più l'idea che precedentemente abbiate parlato di "comprare mele/fiori" però si può usare in senso generico, anche qui molto dipende dalla provenienza e dal contesto.

> Sono entrato nel negozio e ho comprato delle mele. 
>   Ho comprato dei fiori.

ok, le più corrette per esprimere l'indeterminazione

> Mamma mia... come amo le mele.
>   Devo dire che amo i fiori...

corretto....sempre

> Mamma mia... come amo delle mele.
>   Devo dire che amo dei fiori...

NO.

> Mamma mia... come amo mele.
>   Devo dire che amo fiori...

NO

Come vedi la risposta, sopratutto se parliamo di Italiano parlato, non è univoca perché dipende molto dal contesto, dalle parole (quindi il suono) e sopratutto dalla zona di provenienza dell'interlocutore.

Passando alle candele invece :)

> Entro in un negozio e chiedo: avete candele?
>   Si può anche chiedere "avete le candele?" per esprimere "candele in generale", non "candele specifiche"?

1) Se entri in un negozio e chiedi "avete candele?" la risposta è al 10% si/no e per il restante 90% "che candele?"

2) Se entri e chiedi "avete delle candele?" la risposta è al 100% si/no

3) Se entri e chiedi "avete le candele?" la risposta è all'70% si/no e per il restante 30% "che candele?"

Le percentuali variano a seconda della regione. A Roma la 2 e la 3 sono identiche, a Cagliari direbbero più la prima o addirittura un più comune (per la zona) "candele ne avete?".

L'uso corretto grammaticale, per esprimere l'indeterminazione, è comunque il secondo.

Ciao

Comment: Grazie per la risposta argomentata, con cui sono in buona parte d'accordo. Solo una curiosità: che cosa intendi quando dici “corretto”?

Comment: @DaG Figurati. Con "corretto" intendo che è usato comunemente nel parlato e nello scritto. Se posso, visto che sei d'accordo in buona parte, con quale parte non sei d'accordo? :)