# Quale forma dell'articolo si deve usare in questa situazione?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, articles, phrase-choice

La lettura di [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/7143) ha messo dei dubbi sull'uso dell'articolo anche a me.

Immaginate questa situazione. Sono entrata in un supermercato e voglio comprare farina. Cerco una farina qualsiasi e di qualsiasi marca perché non ho ancora deciso quale farina comprare, ma non la trovo. Voglio chiedere aiuto a un commesso del supermercato. Quale tra queste frasi è la corretta in questa situazione?

> - Sto cercando farina.
> - Sto cercando della farina.
> - Sto cercando  la farina.

E se cerco un pane qualsiasi, cosa dovrei dire?

> - Sto cercando pane.
> - Sto cercando del pane.
> - Sto cercando il pane.

Comment: Una curiosità, in spagnolo quale delle tre costruzioni si userebbe?

Comment: @Josh61: Il problema è che in spagnolo non esiste l'articolo partitivo. Io direi: "Estoy buscando **la** harina / Estoy buscando **el** pan". I costrutti senza articolo,  "Estoy buscando harina / Estoy buscando pan", mi sembrano anche corretti però (ma io non li userei).

Comment: Ok capito, grazie.

Comment: Oltre alla risposta di Albert, hai letto già http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/omissione-dell-articolo_(La-grammatica-italiana)/ ?

Comment: L'ho già letto, @mle, ma non vedo che abbia molto a che vedere con la mia domanda.

Answer (score 3):

Cerco "della" farina è generico.

Significa che tu stai cercando un generico tipo di farina.

Cerco "la" farina significa che tu stai specificando il prodotto... Posso dirti che è corretto dire in entrambi i modi, ma sentirai dire

"Cerco la farina 00" per un tipo specifico di farina

"Cerca della farina per una focaccia" è più generico, sembra quasi non importare il tipo di farina.

Ad ogni modo è corretto usare entrambi i modi, solamente una persona super puntigliosa potrebbe fare problemi su un argomento del genere...

Mentre i primi due:

"Cerco farina"

"Cerco pane"

sono completamente sbagliati

Comment: Fanno eccezione frasi che sono diventate idiomatiche come "faccio cose e vedo gente"  di Moretti.

Comment: “Cerco della farina”, da solo, mi suona molto strano: è come se specificassi la quantità (“cerco una manciata di farina”, per esempio) prima ancora di sapere se in quel negozio la vendono, quanto costa, di quali tipi...

Comment: E perché l'omissione dell'articolo sarebbe incorretta? Secondo l'[Enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/articolo_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/): *Va segnalato come, nel caso dei nomi di massa, sia frequente anche l’uso dell’articolo zero: (16) a. c’è del riso nella dispensa? b. c’è riso nella dispensa?*

Comment: E poi spiega: *L’es. (16) b. dà lo spunto per trattare delle costruzioni italiane in cui è possibile l’omissione dell’articolo, senza che, tuttavia, ciò implichi necessariamente la mancanza di un atto di riferimento*

Comment: E un po' più avanti afferma: *In termini generali, un sintagma nominale senza articolo (definito «nudo» in Renzi 1985) è mal tollerato in posizione di soggetto di una frase indipendente dichiarativa; mentre, si è visto, può essere ammesso in posizione di oggetto: (18) Oggetto: ho mangiato riso per due settimane*

Comment: Se si può dire *Ho mangiato riso* perché qui "riso" ha la funzione di oggetto, si dovrebbe anche poter dire "cerco riso", no?

Comment: Curioso, @Charo: ovviamente gli esempi della Treccani sono impeccabili, ma mentre “ho mangiato riso per due settimane” è normale, in *“cerco riso” o anche *“ho cercato riso per due ore” (per fare una frase simile a quella delle due settimane) sembra che parli uno straniero. E non trovo molti altri esempi di complementi oggetti “nudi”: direi “amo il riso”, “è più buono se ci aggiungi il/del riso”, “butta via il riso: è andato a male”. A orecchio direi che c'entri più una serie di costruzioni specifiche per “mangiare”, come “mangiare in bianco” (ma è solo un'ipotesi azzardatissima).

Comment: @DaG: Tu diresti "cerco la farina"?

Comment: @Charo: Sì: “cerco la farina”, “non trovo la farina”, “mi sa dire dove posso trovare la farina?”...

Comment: @DaG: Ma si può omettere l'articolo nei complementi oggetti di altri verbi (comprare, avere...), no?

Comment: @Charo: Per lo più suonerebbe strano. Direi: “Ho comprato la farina”, “Abbiamo il pane o lo compro tornando?” (ma in realtà sarebbe più idiomatico qualcosa come “Il pane ce l'abbiamo o lo compro tornando?”). Forse c'entra col fatto che parliamo di alimenti così comuni. Userei il partitivo in casi come “Compriamo della/un po' di cannella, ché voglio provare a fare una cosa”. Comunque, o il partitivo o l'articolo determinativo lo metterei.

Comment: @DaG: Ho pensato agli esempi dell'altra domanda: "Ho comprato mele." "Avete candele?"

Comment: @DaG: E Vittorio Coletti nel suo libro *Grammatica dell'italiano adulto* spiega: "Il parlante non ha dubbi su quando può o non può usare l'articolo e quando l'uno e quando l'altro. Ad esempio, è di norma omettere l'articolo in «compro oro» (dove *oro* è complemento diretto), ma non potremmo dire «*oro costa caro», bensì «l'oro costa caro» (dove *oro* è soggetto). Però si può dire «risolve problemi» e «problemi si pongono quando...», con *problemi* ora complemento ora soggetto."

Answer (score 3):

Senz'altro l'unica forma idiomatica è, in entrambi i casi, la terza.

È diverso il caso in cui, arrivati al banco del pane, lo ordiniamo: in quel caso, se non abbiamo ancora le idee chiare, diremo qualcosa come “Vorrei del pane” o “un po' di pane” (e ci chiederanno di che tipo).

In generale, l'articolo determinativo è molto più usato di quello che si dedurrebbe dalla semplice contrapposizione determinato/indeterminato (“dammi il libro (di cui abbiamo parlato)/un libro (qualsiasi)”). Per esempio, si direbbe “mi piacciono gli spinaci” (determinando quel tipo di verdura, ma non quali spinaci in particolare, se surgelati o dell'orto del vicino), “dobbiamo ricomprare lo zucchero”, “andiamo a Fiumicino a mangiare il pesce”.