# Quale forma dell'articolo si usa in questa situazione?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, articles, phrase-choice

Vittorio Coletti nel suo libro *Grammatica dell'italiano adulto* spiega:

> Il parlante non ha dubbi su quando può o non può usare l'articolo e quando l'uno e quando l'altro. Ad esempio, è di norma omettere l'articolo in «compro oro» (dove *oro* è complemento diretto), ma non potremmo dire «*oro costa caro», bensì «l'oro costa caro» (dove *oro* è soggetto). Però si può dire «risolve problemi» e «problemi si pongono quando...», con *problemi* ora complemento ora soggetto.

Va bene, forse i parlanti italiani non hanno dubbi sull'uso dell'articolo, ma io ho alcuni dubbi che spero potrete risolvere.

Immaginate che entro in un piccolo negozio di alimentari.  Si tratta di un negozio che non conosco, quindi non so quali articoli si vendono e, per questa ragione, voglio fare alcune domande. Cosa dovrei dire?

> - Avete pane?
> - Avete del pane?
> - Avete il pane?

La stessa domanda con "riso" come sarebbe?

> - Avete riso?
> - Avete del riso?
> - Avete il riso?

Si tratta di domande costruite col verbo "avere" e che riguardano [nomi di massa](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/nomi-di-massa_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/). Vorrei sapere se in questo tipo di domande si usa l'articolo determinativo, l'articolo partitivo oppure l'articolo zero (cioè, nessun articolo).

Comment: Non riesco a cogliere bene la differenza fra questa domanda, la domanda http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/7146/quale-forma-dellarticolo-si-deve-usare-in-questa-situazione e la domanda http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/7146/quale-forma-dellarticolo-si-deve-usare-in-questa-situazione . Mi sembra che in tutti e tre i casi si stia chiedendo (semplificando) “in vari casi in cui si parla di un oggetto generico, come il pane, si usa il partitivo, l'articolo determinativo o niente?” Non sarebbe possibile unificarle? O mi sfugge qualche distinzione?

Comment: @DaG: Ho aggiunto una frase che spero possa mettere in rilievo le differenze. Queste domande, a differenza di quelle di 
http://italian.stackexchange.com/q/7143/707, riguardano "nomi di massa". Secondo l'[Enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/articolo_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/), l'uso degli articoli con i nomi di massa può essere diverso da quello con altri nomi o sintagmi nominali. E il verbo usato nelle frasi (che qui sono domande) è diverso da quello usato in http://italian.stackexchange.com/q/7146/707.

Comment: @DaG: Non sono sicura se sia meglio unificarle. La mia esperienza è che, quando si fa una domanda molto generale, a volte è difficile trovare una risposta.

Comment: @DaG: Tu stesso mi hai fatto vedere che si dice "ho mangiato riso", ma "non trovo il riso". È per questo che penso che il verbo possa fare differenza.

Comment: @DaG: E credo che il fatto che siano domande possa fare anche differenza. La Treccani fa questi esempi: "(16) a. c’è del riso nella dispensa? b. c’è riso nella dispensa?" E poi afferma: "Se volgessimo alla forma dichiarativa l’esempio in (16) b. otterremmo una frase dall’accettabilità dubbia: *c’è riso nella dispensa*. L’inserimento del partitivo *del* o dell’articolo *il* ne ripristinerebbe la piena accettabilità: *c’è del / il riso nella dispensa*."

Comment: Grazie per il chiarimento, Charo!

Comment: *In quella situazione* potresti usare ognuna delle tre forme senza farti troppi problemi e probabilmente la preferenza per una forma o per l'altra può essere dovuta ad abitudine ed influenze dialettali.

Comment: @ErikvanDoren: Potresti scriverlo come risposta? Vedo che in [questo libro](https://books.google.es/books?id=BPvGtYfaQikC&q=%22c'%C3%A8+del+pane%22&dq=%22c'%C3%A8+del+pane%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiy55eSq97NAhXLbRQKHTjpDU4Q6AEIJTAC) si possono leggere domande simili con il partitivo "del".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'uso del partitivo non dipende tanto dal verbo quanto dal contesto. Se ci si riferisce ad un oggetto in particolare, allora diventa **necessario** l'utilizzo dell'articolo determinativo, per esempio:

> "Non riesco a trovare il riso! Eppure mi sembrava di averlo messo in questo scaffale..." (il riso che avevo messo nello scaffale, non del riso in generale)
>
> "Puoi passarmi l'acqua?" (sottintendendo la bottiglia d'acqua sul tavolo)
>
> "Hai preso le crocchette del cane?" (le crocchette del cane, non delle crocchette *per cani*)

Invece se ci si riferisce all'oggetto in senso generico **si può** utilizzare il partitivo:

> "Ho trovato del riso sul pavimento" (non so quale riso sia, nè da dove venga)
>
> "Può darmi dell'acqua?" (ho sete e vorrei dell'acqua, senza specificare quale)
>
> "Hai un cane? Vedo che hai comprato delle crocchette!" (delle crocchette in generale)

Il partitivo è sempre corretto in questo secondo caso, ma è corretta anche la forma con l'articolo determinativo così come quella senza nessun articolo, sebbene a mio parere quest'ultima sia meno usata. Nel caso di frasi negative e interrogative vi è però una maggiore propensione all'utilizzo della forma senza articolo. In ogni caso sono sempre tutte e tre corrette.

Nell'uso quotidiano, a seconda della regione italiana si tende a preferire una forma in particolare, arrivando al punto in cui le forme alternative sembrano innaturali.
Quindi, per rispondere alla tua domanda, dipende dalla regione in cui si trova il negozio

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE e grazie mille della risposta!

Answer (score 0):

Io sono un nativo italiano e userei certamente l'articolo determinativo:
"Avete il riso?" / "Avete il pane?". Mi sembra la forma più appropriata.

Comment: Pensa che invece io direi "avete del pane?" e la versione con l'articolo determinativo mi suona addirittura un pò impacciata... Magari dipende anche dalla regione di nascita di chi parla?

Comment: Certamente! Penso che tu abbia ragione. Io sono del sud Italia
Però sono sicuro che la versione con l'articolo determinativo tu la possa usare un po' dappertutto e suonerebbe abbastanza naturale

Comment: Assolutamente, non ci sono dubbi che usare l'artitolo determinativo sarebbe comunque corretto. Personalmente metterei, in ordine decrescente di preferenza: art. indeterminativo - art. determinativo - nessun articolo.

Comment: Penso che, in quel caso, non usare l'articolo sia proprio scorretto. Non ho mai sentito nessuno dire quel genere di frasi senza usare l'articolo. Ti assicuro che suona davvero molto molto innaturale e poco italiano :)

Comment: @iccanobif: Non è l'"articolo indeterminativo", è l'"articolo partitivo".

Comment: Sentita, ed usata, la forma senza articolo... un esempio... Luigi Meneghello, Opere : *Scendemmo al casotto e gli offrimmo un po di tè.«**Non avete pane?**» disse Lelio. Avevamo finito il pan-biscotto ancora il primo giorno; non c'erano che briciole frammiste alla peluria del sacchetto, e una crosta di formaggio.*

Comment: @Charo sì, giusto, ho fatto confusione.

Comment: Bravo, @ErikvanDoren! Le citazioni da bravi autori arricchiscono sempre il dibattito.

Comment: @ErikvanDoren scusami! Semplicemente suonava innaturale. Nel linguaggio comune non è mai usato. Credetemi

Comment: @G.Recchia Se andassi in un negozio dove non è detto che abbiano pane, ma ci spero, chiederei senza alcuna esitazione “avete pane?”. Ti assicuro che sono di madre lingua italiana. E, sinceramente, “avete il pane?” mi suonerebbe assai strana: la userei per chiedere “il pane che ho ordinato”.

Comment: @egreg forse dipende dalla regione. Dalle mie parti suona molto più naturale "avete il pane?". Non voglio contraddire nessuno. Anzi, molto probabilmente dalle mie parti è sbagliato :)

Comment: @G.Recchia, per me le tre danno un'impressione leggermente differente e mi verrebbe piu' naturale usare una piuttosto che un'altra a seconda del contesto, ma non e' una cosa ragionata, e' un abitudine piu' che altro. Io sono del Veneto e chiedere "avete pane?" mi suona del tutto naturale. Sono sicuro che se entro in un negozio dalle tue parti non farebbero nemmeno caso a che forma uso (nei miei 'anta anni di vita credo che questo sia il momento in cui ci ho pensato piu' a lungo... ;) )